# How to remove eol (plus sign) character in postgres batch output

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running a psql batch script and formatting the output as xml. The problem I am running into is that there is a `+` character in the output. I want to simply use a newline character instead of a plus. I have tried quite a few different arguments and surprised a thorough google search didn't turn up an answer. I am assuming I can use the pset option to change the output eol character but I was unable to get this to work. The script calls query_to_xml on a stored function.

**Calling Batch Script**

```
psql -t -q -U user -h database-qa.example.com -f db_test_query.sql -o output.xml DatabaseToUse
```

**Example Output**

```
<row xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">        +
                                                                   +
   <order_id>12345</order_id>                                      +
   <status_id>ORDER_COMPLETED</status_id>                          +
   <customer_id>9999</customer_id>                                 +
   <company_name>ExampleComany</company_name>                      +
   <main_contact_name>user</main_contact_name>                     +
   <email_address>someone@gmail.com</email_address>                +
   <country_code xsi:nil="true"/>                                  +
   <local_number>1112223333</local_number>                         +
   <address1>1009 Customer Ln</address1>                           +
   <address2></address2>                                           +
   <city>Houston</city>                                            +
   <state_province_geo_id>TX</state_province_geo_id>               +
   <postal_code>77380</postal_code>                                +
   ...
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use unaligned output mode.

```
psql -qAtX ....
```

will suppress informational output (quiet), use unaligned mode, output tuples only, suppress psqlrc reading.

Comment: Note: this may not work anymore with PG client 9.6, because `.psqlrc` now is used with `-c` too (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/release-9-6.html). It seems that not only it is taken into account, but it overrides command line parameters too

Comment: @piro Right, on 9.6 you need `-X` too.

Comment: Isn't it a bit daft the fact `.psqlrc` overrides command line parameters? Let alone all the scripts I have to fix because they work differently for me and for others (but who needs consistency these days: random results for everyone is more fun).

Comment: Yeah, I think it's totally daft. Bugreport-worthy frankly. Though good luck getting it changed due to BC.

Comment: FWIW, [reported](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CA%2Bmi_8a0UeuKLnCvKN2h87dwSgJJTCSxGMr-RzohqfDhPGuf7A%40mail.gmail.com).